# How to insert speech to text in power apps

Tags: azure-web-app-service, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

In microsoft powerapps i am trying to insert speech to text option. However, All the tutorials available on internet are outdated since the powerapps is being updated almost every week and hence, most of the things are changed.

I have till now tried using the `parse JSON` action and used the schema as

```
  `your text`{
     "type": "object",
       "properties": {
          "Url": {
          "type": "string"
     }
   }
 }
```

Which is supposed to change the input into a url according to the tutorial which i was following this url would then be entered into the `convert file` action. However, it is not being coverted into a url.
What wrong am i doing ? Is there any other alternative method to implement speech to text in powerapps?